# what is the zsh bindkey command for vim's dd?

Tags: zsh

i'm trying to remap `dd` to `dl` to match my .vimrc

I read the [docs](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html) for a good while, I couldn't find any command that matches the behavior of `dd` i.e deletes the line and goes to the line above, I tested `bindkey -a dl kill-line`, ... `vi-kill-line`, `kill-whole-line`, `kill-whole-line`, `backward-kill-line`

nor could I find a way to map a sequence to sequence i.e `dd` to `dl`, I also tested it with `bindkey -a dl dd` it doesn't work,

nor could I find a way to bind two/multiple commands like deleting current line and going one line up.

Answer (score 2):

you can define a "widget" with `zle -N <name-of-new-widget>` that triggers a function with the same new widget name that you define, which can run multiple zle commands that emulate vim's `dd`

```
vim-dd() {
    zle kill-whole-line
    zle up-line
}
zle -N vim-dd
bindkey -a dl vim-dd
```